# Is my WaveMaker project corrupt?

Tags: wavemaker

I can no longer test run or deploy my WaveMaker app. I've tried deleting and re-importing the data model, I've tried exporting to a new project, I've tried manually removing suspect files to see if they regenerate fresh. Nothing works. This all seemed to happen after I tried fiddling with the [User Management template](http://dev.wavemaker.com/wiki/bin/Dev/User+Management+template), which may have been a huge mistake.

This is the log I'm seeing:

```
INFO: Manager: undeploy: Undeploying web application at '/RestaurantEntry'
FAIL - No context exists for path /RestaurantEntry
using / as a default project directory; please set projectRoot
checking service RestaurantData
checking service securityService
2014-03-30 11:07:06,616 ERROR [com.wavemaker.runtime.server.JSONRPCController] - <Compile failed with output:

Annotation processing got disabled, since it requires a 1.6 compliant JVM
----------
1. ERROR in /services/RestaurantData/src/com/restaurantdata/RestaurantData.java (at line 32)
return ((TypedServiceReturn) dsMgr.invoke(taskMgr.getReadTask(), rootType, o, propertyOptions, pagingOptions));
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
----------
1 problem (1 error)> (session 1DD52764AA7A917240F4398AD06C06A2, thread 32) 
com.wavemaker.common.WMRuntimeException: Compile failed with output:

Annotation processing got disabled, since it requires a 1.6 compliant JVM
----------
1. ERROR in /services/RestaurantData/src/com/restaurantdata/RestaurantData.java (at line 32)
return ((TypedServiceReturn) dsMgr.invoke(taskMgr.getReadTask(), rootType, o, propertyOptions, pagingOptions));
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
----------
1 problem (1 error)
at com.wavemaker.tools.compiler.ProjectCompiler.compile(ProjectCompiler.java:137)
at com.wavemaker.tools.project.StageDeploymentManager.build(StageDeploymentManager.java:216)
at com.wavemaker.tools.project.LocalDeploymentManager.testRunStart(LocalDeploymentManager.java:111)
at com.wavemaker.tools.project.LocalDeploymentManager.testRunStart(LocalDeploymentManager.java:224)
at com.wavemaker.studio.DeploymentService.testRunStart(DeploymentService.java:91)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.wavemaker.runtime.server.ServerUtils.invokeMethod(ServerUtils.java:347)
at com.wavemaker.runtime.service.reflect.ReflectServiceType.invokeMethod(ReflectServiceType.java:116)
at com.wavemaker.runtime.server.ServerUtils.invokeMethodWithEvents(ServerUtils.java:295)
at com.wavemaker.runtime.server.ControllerBase.invokeMethod(ControllerBase.java:263)
at com.wavemaker.runtime.server.JSONRPCController.executeRequest(JSONRPCController.java:109)
at com.wavemaker.runtime.server.ControllerBase.handleRequestInternal(ControllerBase.java:135)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
INFO: Using default WaveMaker Home folder
```

Answer (score 1):

No, not corrupt, just failing to compile. In particular the imported/generated db service RestaurantData is failing to compile.

Check the JDK being using to compile. The "Annotation processing got disabled, since it requires a 1.6 compliant JVM" message suggests you are not using a 1.6 Compliant Java.

The Java version is reported in the wm.log as part of starting the studio server.

Comment: Here's what the startup log looks like: http://pastebin.com/RQ2SDPmt ...I'm thinking it looks up-to-date, but not really sure.

Comment: Here's another wrinkle...I made a fresh, brand spanking new project and tried to import the sample hrdb and got this: http://pastebin.com/Zd605N53. What on earth have I screwed up?

Comment: It's using JDK 1.8. The generated DB service class doesn't work with 8. You need to have it use 7.
`WaveMaker: Studio Version is 6.7.0.RELEASE
WaveMaker: Java version is 1.8.0
WaveMaker: Starting Tomcat`

Comment: Yes, I figured this out earlier today. Somewhere along the way, I upgraded to 8. As soon as I downgraded back to 7, everything started working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For any other people having this issue, I found installing the relevant jdk-6u45 package from http://uni-smr.ac.ru/archive/dev/java/SDKs/sun/j2se/6/
fixed most of the strange java issues I was having at the beginning.  I had better luck with the x86 one than the 64-bit version in Win 7.  HTH.

Using Wavemaker 6.60 release on IE (Chrome didn't work for some reason).